# type object 'guerrero' has no attribute 'ataque'

Tags: python

Soy nuevo en la programacion, en nuestra clase empezamos a ver python orientado a objetos asi que quisimos hacer algo divertido.
muchos de mis amigos no tenemos experiencia asi me gustaria si pudieran ayudarme

```
class guerrero:
def __init__(self, hp, ataque):
    self.hp = hp
    self.ataque = ataque

def nombre(self):
    print( 'Tu personaje es un guerrero habilidoso y fuerte llamado Rolo')

def coraje(self):
    print("tu personaje se siente valeroso, que el destino decida si gana esta batalla")


def gritobatalla(self):
        print('honor hasta la muerte')

class esqueleto:
    def __init__(self, hpsk, ataquesk):
       self.hpsk = hpsk
       self.ataquesk = ataquesk


    def nombre(self):
         print("SOY SANS, LIDER DE LOS ESQUELETOS DE LA OSCURIDAD")
    def oscuridad(self):
        print("el esqueleto se llena de oscuridad, la batalla sera mas dificil")


atk = random.randint(0,150)
esqueleto=esqueleto(150,atk)


if x == 1:
     print("Te dispones a atacar, la batalla a comenzado")
     lol=random.randint(0,1)
     if lol==0 or lol == 1:
         print("atacas primero")

         esqueleto.nombre()
         esqueleto.oscuridad()
         esqueleto.hpsk=guerrero.ataque()-esqueleto.hpsk()
         print("a tu esqueleto le queda ",esqueleto.hpsl, "de vida")


else:
     print("Para poder escapar nececitas sacar 11 o mas en tu contador")
     op=(random.randint(1, 20))
     if op >= 11:
          print("Tu contador es: ", op)
          print("Logras escapar, el esqueleto no noto tu presencia")
     if op <=10:
          print("Tu contador es: ", op)
          print("Al tratar de escapar hiciste ruido y el esqueleto noto tu presencia, corre hacia ti, prepara tu arma")
```

al correr el programa no sabemos cual es el error
no sabemos mucho de python, nuestra idea era que por medio de randoms era como funcionaria el sistema de lucha y que se restara cada atributo hasta que llegace cada uno a cero y se terminara la batalla
tecnicamente el trabajo como lo pidio nuestro profesor esta completado, pero aun quisiera saber que es lo que ocasiona este mensaje 
saludos y muchisimas gracias

Comment: ¿Qué significa `guerrero.ataque()`? ¿En que parte de la clase guerrero has definido ataque?

Answer (score 2):

Creaste el objeto `esqueleto` pero no el objeto `guerrero`

Haz algo semejante a lo que hiciste en estas dos lineas

```
atk = random.randint(0,150)
esqueleto=esqueleto(150,atk)
```

Algo así.

```
atk = random.randint(0,150)
guerrero1 = guerrero(150,atk)
```

Te sugiero que el nombre de las clases (que construyen a los objetos) los pongas en con la inicial mayúscula. Para evitar problemas en la interpretación de si se debe tomar la clase `esqueleto` o el objeto `esqueleto`.

Por último, no sé si copiaste y pegaste mal tu código, pero tabula los métodos de la clase `guerrero` dentro de su cuerpo.